# Eclipse Project - Plugin or RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse

Complete newbie to Eclipse Project. The current directory structure is as follows:

```
         --configuration
         --jre
         --p2
         --plugins
         Application.exe
         Application.config
         artifacts.xml
```

What kind of a Eclipse project is this? An eclipse Plug-in or an RCP?
I have to build and deploy this onto another server by changing one java source code which has hardcoded connection string.

what is the easiest way that i can build and deploy this?

Any help will greatly be appreciated. Reading up on the internet on a topic that I have very little knowledge of and both look the same - Plugin vs RCP.

TIA,
Bee

Comment: Based on what you've shared it's unlikely anybody can help you.  `--configuration` etc. is not a "directory structure".  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0):

It is an Eclipse RCP with an integrated JRE.

You will need the source code of the RCP projects to rebuild it. The projects should include the files to do the RCP build.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your response.